# How do I stop as a video using HTML5 on close of Modal Window?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched here and all over the web for a way to stop HTML5 video on modal window close. While there has been a lot of answers none seem to work for my site
[The page from my site](http://www.gluedesign.com/work/newgluetwo/video.html#close)

```
<script>
 ("#bone").on('click', function(){
stopVideo();
});
</script>


<a class="button" href="#openModal">Watch Bad to the Bone</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalbg">
<div class="dialog">

<a href="#close"  title="close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"     aria-hidden="true" id="videoToggleOff">C</a>

<video id="bone" src="http://gluedesign.com/work/newgluetwo/video/b2b_7_15a.m4v"  controls width="960" height="540"></video>
<p class="fineprint">Bad To The Bone.</p>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does `stopVideo()` do?

Comment: Have you tried the `$(video).trigger("pause")` or `$(video).pause()`??

Comment: What modal library are you using? They often have events on which you can call your close function. You shouldn't tie it to a button click.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Stop Video, actually the script was lifted from here Stackoverflow - it is 4 years old. I though StopVideo did just that. The entire HTML/Modal code is there. It opens the window, plays the video, closes the window but does not stop the video on close of Modal Window

Comment: You are missing this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js">` above the line: `
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.net/jsapi/38e4f743-f77a-4cfa-9b29-c0f563fdd81b.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

One way to pause/stop video is to do it like this:

```
$("#close").on("click",function(){
  $("#bone").get(0).pause(); // $("#bone").trigger('pause');
});
```

To play the video after clicking on the open modal button:

```
$("#openModalBtn").on("click",function(){
  $("#bone").get(0).play(); // $("#bone").trigger('play');
});
```

For pure javascript, you would need to do it like this:

```
var bone = document.getElementById("bone");
var close = document.getElementById("close");
var openModalBtn = document.getElementById("openModalBtn");
close.addEventListener("click",function(){
  bone.pause();
});

openModalBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
  bone.play();
});
```

And there are few error in the html part as well, you might want to correct them to this:

```
<a id="openModalBtn" class="button" href="#openModal">Watch Bad to the Bone</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalbg">
<div class="dialog">

<a href="#close"  title="close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"     aria-hidden="true" id="close">C</a>

<video id="bone" controls width="960" height="540">
  <source src="http://gluedesign.com/work/newgluetwo/video/b2b_7_15a.m4v">
</video>
<p class="fineprint">Bad To The Bone.</p>
</div>
```

I tested this using a bootstrap modal, but haven't tested it for this one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that in the <head>. to no avail and thank you

Comment: I understood what the problem was, it is not `$("#bone").pause()`, it is `$("#bone").get(0).pause()`. I updated the answer, check it out and tell me if there is any problem.

Comment: Thank you. This does not seem to stick,  I am not using bootstrap. The revision to the HTML presented created a set of new problems. So I reverted to what worked. But the revised JS above still does not stop the movies Even thought the window closes the sound continues. Look here: http://www.gluedesign.com/work/newgluetwo/video.html#close

Comment: are you using jquery??

Comment: A last try, just replace the line `$("#bone").get(0).pause()`  with `document.getElementById("bone").pause()`. If this doesn't work then, I seriously dont know what the problem might be.

Comment: I am using JavaScript HTML5 and CSS3

Comment: So that is the reason why it is not working, the click function you have kept in the question, is related to jquery. But when I look at the console log of your site, it say `$` not define, then that mean jquery is not there.

Comment: You might want to add jquery to your site and test out the jquery version of the solution, but if you do not want to add jquery, then the pure javascript solution should work. If you still have any error, just look at you console.log.

Comment: Integrating JQuery and ID selectors allows me to control all 3 movies on one page

Comment: Yes you can do that, both in javascript and jquery by adding a class to the videos and then implementing the above solution